# document.write hangs and times out

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
        function showtags()
        {
            var tag;
            for(i = 0; i < document.all.length; i++)
            {
                tag = document.all(i).tagName;
                document.write(tag + ' ');
                //document.write("<br>");
            }
        }
        //  -->
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            showtags();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I un-comment the second document.write() in the loop inside the function then it hangs (it does not display anything and times out). I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are creating an infinite loop because you are adding elements to the document, and `document.all` seems to be a collection of all elements. Not sure what you expect as result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.all` is a "live" collection. Each time you loop, you add 2 new items. This means every time it evaluates the `length` property it's always going to be larger than `i`.

Comment: It works with the line commented, it lists all the tags but whennI add the second document.write to display each tag on a new line it starts hanging.

Comment: @user2340048: Why are you repeating what you wrote in your question? Didn't you understand the answer? What's unclear?

Comment: *"Each time you loop, you add 2 new items."* Depends on what you understand by "item". They only add one element if the `document.write("<br>");` is not commented. `document.write(tag + ' ');` does not create an element, only a text node (which is combined with the previous text node, so the number of text nodes does not change, but that's not relevant anyway).

Comment: So document.write("<br>"); is adding element <br> dynamically through the loop and therefore it changes the number of items in the collection. Is that right? If so, any recommendation for line-feed?